# problems with making the square of a number via for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm learning python, now I'm learning for and while, the exercise that I'm doing asks me to make the square of a number using a for loop.
So I'm trying to make it but I don't know how to solve a problem, that I know why it is there, but I don't know how to solve it.

Anyway here's the code

```
def main():
    #start
    givn_n = eval(input("Tell me the number:\n"))
    for i in givn_n:
        #start
        double_givn_n = givn_n ** 2
        print(double_givn_n)
        #end
     return
     #end

main()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\progetto python\Tutorial-python\w ext libraries\somma_quadrati.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\progetto python\Tutorial-python\w ext libraries\somma_quadrati.py", line 6, in main
    for i in givn_n:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I think you mean `for i in range(givn_n)` as the error message says you cannot iterate over `givn_n` that is presumably an integer number. I know this error because I do that myself all the time :)

Comment: thanks man i know tthat is a stupid problem but i'm still learning so i really appreciate  that you gave me the right answer!

Comment: But if you're asked to compute the square of number using a for loop, that's not what you're doing. You're using a for loop to compute the squares of several numbers. How would you compute the square of _one single number_ using a for loop? Think about what a square is ...

Comment: square(6)=36=6*6.  square(9)=81=9*9. Why a loop?  Do you mean 3*3*3, 4*4*4*4, x to the y=x*x...*x (y times) which would require 2 inputs?

Comment: Besides the range problem already mentioned, you need to cast the input from an str to an int.

Comment: @RichardJessop 36=6*6=6+6+6+6+6+6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has already been answered but I want to mention about how to improve your code.

`eval` is a dangerous function. I recommend you to not use it. In your case, `int` can be called.

What about something else. Simple. Try `ast.literal_eval`. Secure way of doing the evaluation.

```
def main():
    # start
    givn_n = int(input("Tell me the number:\n"))
    for i in range(givn_n):
        # start
        double_givn_n = givn_n ** 2
        print(double_givn_n)
        #end
     return # Your code already ends, I think no need to return :)
     #end

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs a small correction

```
for i in range(givn_n):
```

Comment: It's odd when people give answers in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I place the following in a .py script.  Note the need for absolute value:

```
#!python

givn_n = abs(int(input("Tell me the number:\n")))
double_givn_n = 0

for i in range(0,abs(givn_n)):
    double_givn_n += givn_n

print(double_givn_n)
```